# Get the mongo Pool connection stats in NODE JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aws-lambda, connection-pooling

I'm using the MongoDB Pool connection approach to connect my MongoDB using AWS Lambda in NODE JS. I would like to see the number of active pool connections using NODE JS.

I found the cmd line way: [connPoolStats](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/connPoolStats/) But How Can I do it using NODE JS?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using mongoose please follow;

```
let db = mongoose.connection;
db.db.command({ "connPoolStats": 1 }, function (err, result) {
    console.log(result, err);
});
```

If you want to use Native Driver please follow;

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://xxxxx", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}, function (err, client) {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    const database= client.db("database")
    database.command({ "connPoolStats": 1 }, function (err, result) {
        console.log(result, err);
    });

});
```